# How can this be the alternative hypothesis?

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing

I am confused why the correct answer is $\mu_{\text{MLB}} - \mu_{\text{NFL}} > 0$. I thought that was already the assumed null hypothesis?

[image]

Thank you

Comment: The [estimated $\mu_{\text{MLB}}$ is greater than that of $\mu_{\text{NFL}}$](http://onlinestatbook.com/2/logic_of_hypothesis_testing/intro.html), so the alternative hypothesis $\mu_{\text{MLB}} - \mu_{\text{NFL}} > 0$ is accepted.

Comment: The *null* hypothesis is $\mu_{\text{MLB}} - \mu_{\text{NFL}} = 0$